# Null reference error when assigning a value into custom type array via WSDL

Tags: .net, arrays, web-services, nullreferenceexception

I have a WSDL: http://kinkom.dk/WCFAPP/SI_CreateSM_OB_7.wsdl  (I have changed address location).

My code is for accessing data from SAP via WSDL; bind that to .NET control as well as sending data from .NET control to SAP via same WSDL.

The code is like below:

```
// instantiating web service method, web service name is : Webrefence_SM_New2
Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_CreateSM_CR ReqDT = new Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_CreateSM_CR(); 
Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_SM_Response RespDT;

// instantiate cookie to hold the session
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

// Make a proxy of webservice
Webrefence_SM_New2.SI_CreateSM_OBService _proxy1 = new Webrefence_SM_New2.SI_CreateSM_OBService();
_proxy1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx"); // use credential to acess to the SAP system
_proxy1.CookieContainer = cookie;

// binding user input
ReqDT.B_Xn_Type = DDLBusinessTrnscType.SelectedValue;
ReqDT.BP_Function1 = "";
ReqDT.BP_Function2 = "";
ReqDT.BP_Function3 = "";
ReqDT.BP_Function4 = "";

// Error come here when I am assiging a string value
ReqDT.ResourceType[0].Val = "ab";

//The error is: Null Reference Exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
// getting output from WSDL 
RespDT = _proxy1.SI_CreateSM_OB(ReqDT);

// Presenting the output to GUI 
Lblmessageresponse.Text = Convert.ToString(RespDT.Status);
```

On the other way, When I am binding data with .net control at from load event then there is a no problem.

The code is like below:

```
Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_SM_InputHelp_Request IncomingtypeReq = new Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_SM_InputHelp_Request();
Webrefence_SM_New2.DT_SM_InputHelp IncomingTypeResp;

// instantiate cookie to hold the session
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

// Make a proxy of webservice
Webrefence_SM_New2.SI_CreateSM_OBService _proxy1 = new Webrefence_SM_New2.SI_CreateSM_OBService();
_proxy1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx"); // use credential to acess to the SAP system
_proxy1.CookieContainer = cookie;
IncomingtypeReq.OptionalText = "op";
IncomingTypeResp = _proxy1.SI_GetInputHelp(IncomingtypeReq);

// Bind value to Drop down list
DDLStatus.DataSource = IncomingTypeResp.Status;
DDLStatus.DataTextField = "val";
DDLStatus.DataValueField = "val";
DDLStatus.DataBind();
```

It will be great if anyone can help me out how to fix the null reference error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: John: But for me I really can't initialize my array, though the array is custom type and define in a SAP side, but I know the custom type. The array type is DT_Value and array name is: ResourceType and inside array elements are string.  In .NET when I am putting ResourceType[0].Val = "ab" then error come. I can't allocate array like: ReqDT.ResourceType[] rt = new ReqDT.ResourceType[10]; Hence, I can't initialize that. This could be reason for null reference error. But I don't know how to fix it? Any help??

Comment: Use `ReqDT.ResourceType = new DT_Value[10];`. Use whatever size you need if not 10. Then for each `ResourceType` you need to do something like `ReqDT.ResourceType[0] = new DT_Value();`.

Comment: Thanks for this. For example: if I put like ReqDT.ResourceType[0] = new DT_Value("ab"); for passing one fix value, do you think that should work?

Comment: @Paul: yes. You just need to get the elements initialized. Otherwise they have `null`, which gives you `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: hi John: But when I am trying like this: string rs = "resource";

            ReqDT.ResourceType = new DT_Value[10];
            ReqDT.ResourceType = new DT_Value(rs); then error come like ""WebApplication1.Webreference_SM_New4.DT_value" doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 argument". Do know where is the wrong?

Comment: John: Thanks, But I need to pass at least a value through ResourceType, How that will pass then?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ReqDT.ResourceType = new DT_Value[10];
ReqDT.ResourceType[0] = new DT_Value();
ReqDT.ResourceType[0].val = "ab";
```

Comment: Dear John,I am so grateful to you. It's working now. If you live in Copenhagen, Denmark I could invite for dinner!! :)

Comment: @Paul: You're welcome. You can thank me by reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net and learning how to avoid the next few NullReferenceExceptions that you otherwise would have seen.

Comment: Hi John, Do you know how to work with SOAP attachment? If you have a good example please forward that.

Comment: @Paul: don't ask me - ask StackOverflow. Ask a separate question.

Comment: Hi John, I will be grateful if you have time to see the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442160/method-cant-return-value-error-can-not-convert-type-in-c-asp-net