# method can't return value, Error: can not convert type in C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have method that should return a set of data. But at last when returning data then error shows like :"can not convert type 'WebApplication1.Webrefernce13.DT_value[]' to 'WebApplication1.Webrefernce13.DT_value"

```
public class InputHelp
{
    public DT_Value Priority()
    {
        WebReference13.DT_SM_InputHelp_Request IncomingtypeReq = new WebReference13.DT_SM_InputHelp_Request();

        WebReference13.DT_SM_InputHelp IncomingTypeResp;
        WebReference13.SI_CreateSM_OBService _proxy1 = new WebReference13.SI_CreateSM_OBService();
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        _proxy1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxxx"); // use credential to acess to the SAP system
        _proxy1.CookieContainer = cookie;

        IncomingtypeReq.Mode = "Create";
        IncomingtypeReq.Language = "EN";

        IncomingtypeReq.OptionalText1 = "ZLFN";

        IncomingtypeReq.OptionalText2 = "";
        IncomingtypeReq.WSCallID = "223424dgdf";

        IncomingTypeResp = _proxy1.SI_GetInputHelp(IncomingtypeReq);

        DT_Value[] ab=new DT_Value[10];

        ab= IncomingTypeResp.Priority;

        return ab;  // error is here
    }
```

I will be grateful if you can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method signature to

```
public DT_Value[] Priority(){...}
```

also

```
    DT_Value[] ab=new DT_Value[10];
    ab = IncomingTypeResp.Priority; //<-- something doesn't look right here.
```

if `IncomingTypeResp.Priority` is of type `DT_Value[]` then you can just do

```
 DT_Value[] ab = IncomingTypeResp.Priority;
```

Comment: Hi Bala, Thanks a lot, It's works fine!! There is a one more question, if you have a look on the code, I am calling web service. But If I make one more method then I have call the web service again inside the method scope. But I want to minimize the web service. Would mind to say how can I do that? /Paul

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `ab` as an array of `DT_Value`, but the method returns `DT_Value` (a single `DT_Value` instance).

If you want `Priority` to return an array you should change the declaration to this:

```
public DT_Value[] Priority()
```

Comment: @Paul, if i've answered your question, please mark it as an answer (click the green tick next to the answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining ab as an array of DT_Value but the method contract is to return only one DT_Value.  If you want to return only the first value (if it exists), make your last line

```
return ab[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare like below and might help you:

```
DT_Value ab=new DT_Value;
```